# Can I enter the Schengen area after previously staying there for 89 days in the past 6 months?

Tags: schengen, visa-free-entry, visa-expiration

I (US citizen) was in the Schengen area (Sweden) for 2.5 months a few months ago (so I am close to 90/180). As a US citizen, I entered under the visa-free agreement (EC 539/2001 Annex II).

I am looking at plane tickets for another trip into the Schengen area, again via the visa-free agreement.

Will border control (in Sweden) allow me entry into their country if my flight back home is on day 89 or 90 of the allowed 90-day period?

I have not found any information online about any leeway requirement, here or via Google.

---

Due to the Schengen rule requiring passport not expire for 3 additional months after visa expiry or the US's six-month-past-visa-expiry requirement, this seems like a a reasonable question to ask more seasoned travelers than I.

Note: I will not exceed 90-days out of 180-days limit at any time.

(Leaving a few days earlier/entering a bit later so there is a bit of space just in case something goes wrong is be preferable, of course, but I'd like to maximize my stay.)

Comment: All other things being equal and you are not otherwise detained, yes that's fine.

Comment: No, there's no leeway in the 90/180 rule. But there's also no reason they should stop you or if your plan remains within the 90/180.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You don't need any leeway if you're not trying to stay more than 90/180.

Answer (score 3):

> Will border control (in Sweden) allow me entry into their country if my flight back home is on day 89 or 90 of the allowed 90-day period?

Yes, in so far as they will not refuse you for that alone.